# Why my python script is not printing anything

Tags: python

I have a problem..whenever I am writing any Python script say like this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print "hello"
```

Then using

```
chmod +x a.py
```

And then write `./a.py` then it is not printing anything in the terminal

Moreover whenever I write any comment below the shabang line, it gives me an error saying 
`#: bad interpreter : No such file or directory`

but when I run the script like this `python a.py` it works as usual..

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix this..

Comment: Try running `which python`

Comment: I always use "#!/usr/bin/env python", which automatically locates python in your environment.

Comment: I have the correct Python path...one more thing..when I open this file in vim, it tells me `noeol` but while opening other files it is not telling me and hence other files are working properly

Comment: I'm fairly certain if your path was correct you wouldn't be receiving this error.

Comment: I am not receiving this error on other python files using the same Python path

Comment: Could it be that somehow the line end character in the `#!` line is bad?

Comment: @ThatGuyRussell...this is not a syntax error

Comment: @tobais_k can you please elaborate

Comment: Shouldn't you be using something like `#!/usr/local/bin python`? What you have looks like it is just a directory path.

Comment: @martineau it's supposed to be the path to the executable program, which will be run with the script file as its standard input. As you wrote it, it would try to run the directory `/usr/local/bin` with `"python"` as an argument

Comment: @holdenweb: I use the first form shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines), `/usr/bin/env python`, which is supposedly "portable between Unix and Windows". However that doesn't jive with what you're saying (although the other alternatives do).

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is a program. `/usr/local/bin` is a directory.

Comment: @holdenweb: Oh, I get it — thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your line ending is a carriage-return/line feed combination - which Windows-style editors will create. Unix regards the LF as the end of the line, so it's looking for an executable called `"python\r"`. When you run it with an explicit call to the interpreter the shebang line is just treated as a comment.

Comment: I tried the \r option too..I think that there is some problem with the file..because this error is not present for other Python files..needless to say that this file shows noeol ( no end of line) below while others are not showing that

Comment: What do you mean you "tried the \r option too"? Just make sure there are no carriage returns in the file

Comment: @holdenweb oups, sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Under linux text replacement fix:

```
sed -i 's/^ M//g' filename
```

(note that ^ M is written in linux, press ^ M is carriage return and line feed, the input method is to hold down CTRL + v, release v, press m)

This solve bad endline for shell in first line if error message looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/python3 ^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```